# How to call Parent Page property in UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls

I have my parent page as **OPC.aspx** where **Addressdetail.ascx** is declared as usercontrol.

Now I have made one **property** in my parent page(OPC.aspx) as

```
public string SelectedOptionUserControl { get; set; }
```

Now I want to set property named **SelectedOptionUserControl** in usercontrol(Addressdetail.ascx) i.e. I want to set the property of parent page in child page

on **Addressdetail.ascx**  code below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     this.Page.Master.SelectedOptionUserControl="abc";
     this.Page.GetType().InvokeMember("SelectedOptionUserControl", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.Page, new object[] { "abc" });
    }
```

I have tried this 2 ways but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
public string SelectedOptionUserControl { get; set; }
```

declares a property, not a method.

So change

```
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
```

To

```
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty
```

Comment: getting null I had checked in quick watch